# Non-trivial solutions to $w^n = x^n + y^n + z^n$, for $n>4$

Tags: number-theory

We know that $6^3 = 5^3 + 4^3 + 3^3$ and $422481^4=414560^4+217519^4+95800^4$ (due to Roger Frye, 1988). But does $w^n = x^n + y^n + z^n$ have non-trivial solutions for $n>4$? By non-trivial I mean that all terms are distinct positive integers.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226093/rational-solutions-of-the-fermat-equation-xnynzn-1/226146#226146

Comment: Wow thank you!!

Comment: @individ the answer you linked to doesn't work as it involves imaginary numbers. I am looking for real integer solutions here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been answered on MathOverflow. It is a good question, but we try to keep duplication to a minimum.